# Migrations and Integration Tests running very slow despite almost empty DB

Tags: php, mariadb, integration-testing, database-migration

As stated above both my migrations and integrations tests are running very slowly.
The migrations that are done in about 5 seconds for ~110 Migrations on other computers take sometimes 15 seconds+ for just one.

The integration Tests take usually around 5 minutes for 500 Tests on other machines and I need 30 minutes.

The computer is running ubuntu as my coworkers.
I´ve found out that there are some problems with big databases but my database is empty when doing the migrations and only has less than 100 rows alltogether when testing.

I´m using Ubuntu 18.04.5, PHP 7.4.9 & MariaDB V15.1D10.1.44

Comment: What toll is doing the "migration" and "integration"?  Is it MariaDB 10.1.44 on both machines?

Comment: how do you mean? My Coworker had another Version, so I updated, but the problem persists

Comment: I have not heard of the tool "Coworker".